# twig autoescaping html tags

Tags: html, symfony, escaping, twig

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% set label = '<i class="flaticon solid plus-1"></i>Add User'|raw %}
{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': label }) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This is the output

```
&lt;i class="flaticon solid plus-1"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;Add User
```

How do I get it to not escape? If I just print out label instead of supplying it as a parameter to the "form_row" function, it prints out properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `|raw` filter at the wrong place - it is only processed when *outputting* data, not when *setting a variable*. You should patch it into the `form_row` function, or append it to it's call - can't be sure without seeing how that function works.

Most probably this will fix it:

```
{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': label })|raw }}
```

Since I assume it returns the modified string and lets the `{{` tags handle output.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. Still outputs the same.

Comment: As said, I can't see what `form_row` does without that code, so it's guesswork for me as well.

Comment: I will attempt to modify the function now and will let you know how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

in form_div_layout.html.twig

change

`<button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</button>`

to

`<button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw }}</button>`

This seems like a hacky solution, since I'm modifying the stuff in the vendor folder.